# Передача данных между фрагментами хостящимися на разных Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment

Здравствуйте! Имеются два фрагмента, каждый из которых имеет хост-Activity. В первом фрагменте имеется GridView с картинками при щелчке на которой должен открываться фрагмент 2 с этим изображением на полный размер экрана. Вопрос каким образом передать сведения на какую картинку кликнул пользователь из первого фрагмента во второй

Fragment send:

```
public static AlbumFragment newInstance(int position) {
    AlbumFragment fragment = new AlbumFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("EXTRA_IMAGE_POSITION", position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}
```

Fragment receive

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Integer imPos = bundle.getInt(AlbumFragment.EXTRA_IMAGE_POSITION);
        Log.d(TAG, "get position " + imPos);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Создаете интерфейс который будет реализовывать первое активити. Интерфейс может выглядеть следующим образом

```
public interface OnFragmentInteraction {
    void imageClicked(String pathToImg);
}
```

Дальше в первом фрагменте в методе `onAttach(Activity activity)` получаете ссылку на реализацию данного интерфейса следующим образом:

```
private OnFragmentInteraction listener;

public void onAttach(Activity activity){

    if(activity instanceOf OnFragmentInteraction){
        listener = (OnFragmentInteraction)activity;
    }
}
```

После чего в методе обработчике нажатия на изображения выполняете следующее:

```
if(listener != null){
    listener.imageClicked(pathToImg);
}
```

Первое активити должно иметь следующий код:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity implements OnFragmentInteraction {

    public void imageClicked(String pathToImg) {
        //запускаем новое активити, и передаем в него путь до файла через Bundle
    }
}
```

Где в методе `imageClicked(String pathToImg)` создаете `Intent` для запуска нового активити, и через Bundle передаете путь до изображения, а в методе `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)` забираете этот путь и передаете его дальше во второй фрагмент по обычной схеме.

Если у фрагментов одна хостовая активити, то тогда в методе `imageClicked(String pathToImg)` запускаете не вторую активити, а второй фрагмент и передаете в него путь до изображения.

Answer (score 1):

Почти все рано или поздно приходят к тому, что проще и удобнее использовать [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) для всех коммуникаций в приложении.